# how to retrieve a value that is entered on localhost from another model

Tags: php, cakephp, get

First of all, let me clarify myself. I baked something on cakephp and entering values on localhost in that application. Basicly, there are 2 models called `location` and `temp_readings`.

In `location` model, there are temperature limits that are called `high_temp` and `low_temp`. and also the name of the location. I enter those values, (e.g. `name= fridge, low_temp= 3, high_temp= 7`)

In `temp_readings` model, I enter a temperature a value for a specific location, (e.g. `temperature= 10, location= frigde`).

If temp value is out of limits, my app sending a warning email to me.

I work on `temp_readings.php` script for doing that and i need to put that condition for sending email.

I think, i can get the value of temperature by writing;

```
 $temperature = $this->data['temp_readings']['temperature'];
```

since i am working in `temp_readings.php`.

However, i cannot get the values of `low_temp` and `high_temp`, which are saved under location model.

**How can I get low_temp and high_temp values to work in temp_readings.php?**

***Here is the part of temp_readings.php (I dont know if it helps)***

```
class temp_readings extends AppModel {

function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {

//pr($this);

//$temperature = $this->data['TemperatureReading']['temperature'];

//$low_temp=

//$high_temp=

    if ($temperature > $high_temp && $temperature < $low_temp) {

    $Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
    $Email->from(array('****@gmail.com' => 'My Site'));
    $Email->to('***@gmail.com');
    $Email->subject('Temperature Warning!');
    $Email->send('Temperature is at critical value of');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `belongsTo` relationship between `temp_readings` and `location`, like so:

```
class temp_readings extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = [
        'location' // I don't know your data structure, but you'll probably need to add some details here
    ];

    /* ... */
}
```

Then, after saving:

```
function afterSave($created, $options = array()) {
    $temperature = $this->data['TemperatureReading']['temperature'] ;
    $location    = $this->data['Location'] ;
    /* ... */
}
```

Of course, this code needs changes because I don't know your database structure but it should give you a hint on what you should do.